# How to get Table "tr" count on PHP submission

Tags: php, html

For I want output like simliar : 
Total Row: 3.

I know to get table tr count using jquery , but i need it from php. please help.

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $rows = $table->find('#dataTable'); 
  $count = count($rows);                
  echo $count;
}
?>
<form method="post" action=""><br/>
<table width="250" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Table Count"/>
</form>
```

Example i have 3 rwo 2 column table with #dataTable, When i submit using php i want the table

Comment: What is `$table`?

Comment: This will not work because the rows and its elements are not transmitted, only form elements like e.g. input type = hidden will be transmitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work because the rows and its elements are not transmitted.
So I added a hidden field every row.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $rows = $_POST['hidden'];
  $count = count($rows);                
  echo $count;
}
?>
<form method="post" action=""><br/>
<table width="250" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1<input type="hidden" name="hidden[]" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2<input type="hidden" name="hidden[]" value="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3<input type="hidden" name="hidden[]" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Table Count"/>
</form>
```

btw., in your shown code it looks like you mix jQuery with PHP. Which doesn't work because jQuery is client side and PHP is server side.

Answer (score 0):

You could enter the number of rows in a hidden input before sending the form

Comment: Thanks, Currently as of now from hidden input taking row count. is there any option ?